# Redux Saga Watch Multiple Action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

My Saga Root looks like this

```
export default function* root() {
  yield takeLatest(LOAD_SEARCHRESULTS, getSearchResults);
}
```

it watches LOAD_SEARCHRESULTS action and then calls getSearchResults function.

Is there any way I can watch multiple actions in root?
Something like this:

```
export default function* root() {
  yield takeLatest(LOAD_SEARCHRESULTS, getSearchResults);
  yield takeLatest(CHANGE_ALIASFILTER, getSearchResults);
  yield takeLatest(CHANGE_CATFILTER, getSearchResults);
}
```

So if any of those action comes in - it calls getSearchResults. I have tried yield all([]) and takeEvery but it only watches for first action.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) can also take an array of actions, so you just need to do

```
export default function* root() {
  yield takeLatest([LOAD_SEARCHRESULTS, CHANGE_ALIASFILTER, CHANGE_CATFILTER], getSearchResults);
}
```

Another option is to use `all` and `fork`, like [here](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/real-world/sagas/index.js#L122)

Comment: Can we do it the opposite way? Like this: `yield takeLatest(LOAD_SEARCHRESULTS, [getSearchResults, getTotalResults]);`. So as we listen to one action and when it fires we call two methods.

Comment: @jake-ferguson takeLatest defined as `takeLatest(pattern, saga, ...args)`, when saga is a generator function. So passing multiple sagas seems to be unsupported. I think the only way is to wrap these two sagas into one.